# UserData script with Resource Attribute CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, yaml, aws-cloudformation

**The main question:** How to I reference dependent resource attributes in a cloud formation template to build out a user data script.

**What I have tried**:

1. Approach listed [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/blob/master/aws/services/CloudFormation/FindInMap_Inside_Sub.yaml).
2. Examples from [sub function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html)

I am building a CloudFormation template for a three node Kafka cluster.

The approach I am taking here is configuring Zookeeper and Kafka on each node of the cluster using a UserData script on the EC2 instance.

I am using the [Sub](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) and [Base64](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-base64.html) functions to populate my user data script with the `PrimaryPrivateIpAddress` of my NetworkInterface but they are coming across as empty strings instead of the actual values. I know that the values are being populated correctly because they are part of my output in the template.

I have included the resource block of my template below as a reference. I omitted some uninteresting parts for the sake of succinctness. I also am illustrating a couple different approaches that I have tried to the EC2 resource blocks are not consistent.

```
EC2I8MWW:
  Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
  DependsOn:
    - EC2NI2E8ES
    - EC2NI2PFST
    - EC2NI54B66
  Properties:
    KeyName: !Ref DesiredKeyName
    InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
    NetworkInterfaces:
      - NetworkInterfaceId: !Ref EC2NI54B66
        DeviceIndex: "0"
    UserData:
      Fn::Base64:
        Fn::Sub:
          - |
            #!/bin/bash
            CONF="/etc/zookeeper/conf.dist/zoo.cfg"
            PRIVATE_1=${Private1}
            PRIVATE_2=${Private2}
            PRIVATE_3=${Private3}
            echo "# Zookeeper configuration for Talentreef" > "$CONF"
            cat <<EOT >> "$CONF"
            maxClientCnxns=50
            tickTime=2000
            initLimit=10
            syncLimit=5
            EOT
            echo "server.1=$PRIVATE_1:2888:3888" >> $CONF
            echo "server.2=$PRIVATE_2:2888:3888" >> $CONF
            echo "server.3=$PRIVATE_3:2888:3888" >> $CONF
            service zookeeper-server init --myid=$NODE_ID
            chkconfig zookeeper-server on
          - {
            Private1: !GetAtt EC2NI2E8ES.PrimaryPrivateIpAddress,
            Private2: !GetAtt EC2NI2PFST.PrimaryPrivateIpAddress,
            Private3: !GetAtt EC2NI54B66.PrimaryPrivateIpAddress
            }
EC2I2JVJI:
  Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
  DependsOn: EC2NI54B66
  Properties:
    KeyName: !Ref DesiredKeyName
    InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
    BlockDeviceMappings:
      - DeviceName: /dev/xvdb
        Ebs:
          VolumeType: st1
          DeleteOnTermination: 'true'
          VolumeSize: '500'
      - DeviceName: /dev/xvda
        Ebs:
          VolumeType: gp2
          DeleteOnTermination: 'true'
          VolumeSize: '8'
    ImageId: !FindInMap
      - AWSRegionArch2AMI
      - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
      - !FindInMap
        - AWSInstanceType2Arch
        - !Ref InstanceType
        - Arch
    NetworkInterfaces:
      - NetworkInterfaceId: !Ref EC2NI2PFST
        DeviceIndex: "0"
    UserData:
      Fn::Base64: !Sub |
        #!/bin/bash
        CONF="/etc/zookeeper/conf.dist/zoo.cfg"
        cp $CONF /etc/zookeeper/conf.dist/zoo.cfg.bak-$(date +%s)
        echo "# Zookeeper configuration for Talentreef" > "$CONF"
        cat <<EOT >> "$CONF"
        maxClientCnxns=50
        tickTime=2000
        initLimit=10
        syncLimit=5
        server.1=${EC2NI2E8ES.PrimaryPrivateIpAddress}:2888:3888
        server.2=${EC2NI2PFST.PrimaryPrivateIpAddress}:2888:3888
        server.3=${EC2NI54B66.PrimaryPrivateIpAddress}:2888:3888
        EOT
        service zookeeper-server init --myid=$NODE_ID
        chkconfig zookeeper-server on
        service zookeeper-server start
EC2I56LVQ:
  Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
  DependsOn: EC2NI54B66
  Properties:
    KeyName: !Ref DesiredKeyName
    InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
    BlockDeviceMappings:
      - DeviceName: /dev/xvdb
        Ebs:
          VolumeType: st1
          DeleteOnTermination: 'true'
          VolumeSize: '500'
      - DeviceName: /dev/xvda
        Ebs:
          VolumeType: gp2
          DeleteOnTermination: 'true'
          VolumeSize: '8'
    ImageId: !FindInMap
      - AWSRegionArch2AMI
      - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
      - !FindInMap
        - AWSInstanceType2Arch
        - !Ref InstanceType
        - Arch
    NetworkInterfaces:
      - NetworkInterfaceId: !Ref EC2NI2E8ES
        DeviceIndex: "0"
    UserData:
      Fn::Base64:
        Fn::Sub:
          - |
            CONF="/etc/zookeeper/conf.dist/zoo.cfg"
            cp $CONF /etc/zookeeper/conf.dist/zoo.cfg.bak-$(date +%s)
            echo "# Zookeeper configuration for Talentreef" > "$CONF"
            cat <<EOT >> "$CONF"
            maxClientCnxns=50
            tickTime=2000
            initLimit=10
            syncLimit=5
            EOT
            echo "server.1=${Private1}:2888:3888" >> $CONF
            echo "server.2=${Private2}:2888:3888" >> $CONF
            echo "server.3=${Private3}:2888:3888" >> $CONF
            service zookeeper-server init --myid=$NODE_ID
            chkconfig zookeeper-server on
          - {
            Private1: !GetAtt EC2NI2E8ES.PrimaryPrivateIpAddress,
            Private2: !GetAtt EC2NI2PFST.PrimaryPrivateIpAddress,
            Private3: !GetAtt EC2NI54B66.PrimaryPrivateIpAddress
            }
EC2NI54B66:
  Type: 'AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface'
  DependsOn: EC2NI2PFST
  Properties: {}
EC2NI2PFST:
  Type: 'AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface'
  DependsOn: EC2NI2E8ES
  Properties {}
EC2NI2E8ES:
  Type: 'AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface'
  Properties: {}
```

When this script runs I get the following output in the `zoo.cfg` file:

```
maxClientCnxns=50
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
server.1=:2888:3888
server.2=:2888:3888
server.3=:2888:3888
```

Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong here or if I have to change my approach. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you're on the right path. I would just modify a bit the way you pass the 3 "private" substitute variables, for something like this (which I use quite often in my templates):

```
UserData:
  Fn::Base64:
    Fn::Sub:
      - |
        CONF="/etc/zookeeper/conf.dist/zoo.cfg"
        cp $CONF /etc/zookeeper/conf.dist/zoo.cfg.bak-$(date +%s)
        echo "# Zookeeper configuration for Talentreef" > "$CONF"
        cat <<EOT >> "$CONF"
        maxClientCnxns=50
        tickTime=2000
        initLimit=10
        syncLimit=5
        EOT
        echo "server.1=${Private1}:2888:3888" >> $CONF
        echo "server.2=${Private2}:2888:3888" >> $CONF
        echo "server.3=${Private3}:2888:3888" >> $CONF
        service zookeeper-server init --myid=$NODE_ID
        chkconfig zookeeper-server on
      - Private1: !GetAtt EC2NI2E8ES.PrimaryPrivateIpAddress
        Private2: !GetAtt EC2NI2PFST.PrimaryPrivateIpAddress
        Private3: !GetAtt EC2NI54B66.PrimaryPrivateIpAddress
```

So no brackets `{}` and no commas `,`

Comment: Thanks! I also had some bad bash in there so I fixed that as well and things are working.

Comment: thank you, it solved my issue also in using !GetAtt in Userdata