# AWS CloudFormation YAML - reference an instance's private IP that was created in the same stack to be written to a config file

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, yaml, aws-cloudformation

All,

I am trying to reference an instance's private IP that is created in the same stack this configuration file is written. The instance is called "instance" and according to AWS documentation found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getatt.html) I should be able to reference the private IP by using the below formatting.

When I build the stack everything completes successfully but the log file literally has `"!GetAtt instance.PrivateIp Example text here"` written in it rather than the private IP. I tried using ${instance.PrivateIp} which did not work because it created a circular reference in the stack.

Is there some other way that I should be referencing the private IP of this instance?

Thanks!

```
# Write config file
cat << EOF > /config.conf
!GetAtt instance.PrivateIp ${String1}
EOF
```

Edit: Looks like it can't be done because CFN is trying to query the resource that is in the process of creating. Hope this questions helps others that attempt to the same thing that I did here.

Answer (score 0):

The parser should try to substitute text after it sees the "${" characters... 
Did you try ${instance.PrivateIp} ?

Comment: Yup, it failed because it's creating a circular reference to a property that technically isn't created until this resource finishes its creation.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your cloud-init script to query the private IP from the AWS metadata service:

```
EC2_INSTANCE_ID=`wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4`
```

Comment: This will work if we need to get instance ID of the same instance. Any idea what if I want to refer to another instance being created in the same CF Stack

Comment: Could you explain your use case? Sometimes there are easier workarounds.

Comment: I actually wanted to refer Private IPs of the instances being launched in same stack, to create a kind of cluster of instances. I was able to find solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48625737/userdata-script-with-resource-attribute-cloudformation