# Aws cloudformation get private IP address of one ec2 instance to another ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I created two Amazon EC2 instances in AWS CloudFormation using a YAML template. I want to take private IP address of one EC2 instance to the other EC2 instance which has a public IP address. As per AWS documentation we can do that using `!GetAtt JMeterServer1Instance.PrivateIp`

1. I want to know under which section of the public EC2 instance I should add that in the template. (Please consider this is a YAML template.)
2. How do I check that we have received it?

Comment: What do you mean by "take private IP address of one EC2 instance to the other EC2 instance"? Do you mean you want to be able to reference the IP address of Instance-A in the User Data section of Instance-B?

Comment: Assume i have 2 ec2 instances as A and B created with aws yaml cloud formation template. A has a private ip and B has a public ip.I run some performance tests on instance A. Then i want to communicate with instance B and take the results available on instance A to instance B. To fullfill a requirement like that i need to somehow take the ip address of insatnce A to the user data section of instance B

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that your requirement is:

- Create two instances in a CloudFormation template
- In the User Data for Instance-A, refer to Instance-B

This is quite simple. First, define that Instance-B `DependsOn` Instance-A to ensure the creation of Instance-A before Instance-B.

Then, in the User Data for Instance-B, refer to Instance-A:

```
  UserData:
    "Fn::Base64":
      !Sub |
        #!/bin/bash
        echo "${InstanceA.PrivateIp}" >foo
```

A 'better' method would be to use DNS names with a **Hosted Zone for VPC in Route 53**. This would create a DNS zone for the VPC, then define a DNS name that can be resolved locally. Link it to Instance-B and then Instance-A could refer to Instance-B by DNS name rather than IP address. This allows the DNS name to point to a different instance in future if desired, and creates less dependencies between Instance-A and Instance-B. (But, admittedly, more setup.)

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted. Thank you very much..  :)

Answer (score 2):

As per the [AWS document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getatt.html)

> Fn::GetAtt

will do the trick here.

My case is:

1. EC2Instance001 needs to be created 1st
2. EC2Instance002 needs to use IP of EC2Instance001.

At EC2Instance002 instance is created with two specific settings:

- "DependsOn": [ "EC2Instance001"] as I want EC2Instance001 to be created first.
- Under Userdata (or metadata) use { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "EC2Instance001", "PrivateIp" ] } for getting IP of 1st Instance (EC2Instance001)

Here is how I achieved it (EC2Instance002):

```
---
EC2Instance002:
  Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
  Metadata:
    AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
      configSets:
        InstallAndRun:
        - Install
        - Configure
      Install:
        packages:
          yum:
            git: []
        files:
          "/tmp/bootstrap.sh":
            content:
              Fn::Join:
              - ''
              - - "#!/bin/bash\n"
                - 'set -x

'
                - 'echo "============================"

'
                - 'sudo hostname >> /tmp/EC2Instance.txt

'
                - MASTERIP=
                - Fn::GetAtt:
                  - EC2Instance001
                  - PrivateIp
                - "\n"
                - "echo $MASTERIP > masterIP.txt \n"
          mode: '755'
          owner: ec2-user
          group: ec2-user
      Configure:
        commands:
          runBootstrapScript:
            command: "./bootstrap.sh"
            cwd: "/tmp"
  DependsOn:
  - EC2Instance001
  Properties:
    InstanceType:
      Ref: InstanceType
    SecurityGroups:
    - Ref: InstanceSecurityGroup
    KeyName:
      Ref: KeyName
    UserData:
      Fn::Base64:
        Fn::Join:
        - ''
        - - "#!/bin/bash -xe\n"
          - 'yum install -y aws-cfn-bootstrap

'
          - "# Install the files and packages from the metadata\n"
          - "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init  -v"
          - "         --stack "
          - Ref: AWS::StackName
          - "         --resource EC2Instance002 "
          - "         --configsets InstallAndRun "
          - "         --region "
          - Ref: AWS::Region
          - "\n"
    ImageId:
      Fn::FindInMap:
      - AWSRegionArch2AMI
      - Ref: AWS::Region
      - Fn::FindInMap:
        - AWSInstanceType2Arch
        - Ref: InstanceType
        - Arch
```

You can see that under Metadata I am capturing IP of **EC2Instance001** instance in variable **$MASTERIP**.

**NOTE:** Same line in JSON will be written as:

```
"MASTERIP=",{ "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "EC2Instance001", "PrivateIp" ] }, "\n",
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you'd like to with the private IP on the other machine.
If you'd like to use it in a script on the other VM, pass it down in the user data script like in this example: [UserData script with Resource Attribute CloudFormation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48625737/userdata-script-with-resource-attribute-cloudformation)

The example on the link is showing the attribute of a `NetworkInterface` instead of an instance attribute, but it's the same with `!GetAtt JMeterServer1Instance.PrivateIp`