# Reference ID of resource in Userdata Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm writing a cloudformation template in YAML format.
Now i'm stuck with appending  the id of the ebs volume to ec2 user data.

```
    Type: AWS::EC2::Volume
    Properties:
      Size: 50
      AvailabilityZone: ap-southeast-1b
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: Logstash Volume
  LogStashMountPoint:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VolumeAttachment
    Properties:
      InstanceId:
        Ref: LogstashInstance
      VolumeId:
        Ref: LogstashVolume
      Device: "/dev/xvdf"        
  LogstashInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      IamInstanceProfile:
          Ref: LogstashInstanceProfile                 
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      KeyName: chuongtest
      ImageId: ami-0cd31be676780afa7
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64:
          Fn::Sub:
            - |
              #!/bin/bash -xe
              echo ${LogstashVolume} >> /home/ec2-user/ebsid.txt
              {LogstashVolume: Ref: LogstashVolume}
              touch /home/ec2-user/ebscomplete.txt          
              curl "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id" >> /home/ec2-user/ec2id.txt 
              touch /home/ec2-user/ec2complete.txt           
              touch /home/ec2-user/complete.txt
            - LogstashVolume: !Ref LogstashVolume    
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - Ref: LogstashSecurityGroup
      SubnetId: subnet-0d0e0989f57b96389
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: Logstash Instance
```

[UserData script with Resource Attribute CloudFormation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48625737/userdata-script-with-resource-attribute-cloudformation)
I'm following this link but it still doesn't work
When the new instance is launched. It has nothing in /home/ec2-user.
I looked everywhere and this is my final but it didn't work
Can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is at least one **syntax error** in your `UserData`:

```
echo ${LogstashVolume}) >> /home/ec2-user/ebsid.txt
```

should be

```
echo ${LogstashVolume} >> /home/ec2-user/ebsid.txt
```

For further debugging of your `UserData`, login to the instance and check `/var/log/could-init-output.log` file.

p.s.

The following is also incorrect:

```
{LogstashVolume: Ref: LogstashVolume}
```

Its not a valid bash command.

Comment: Yeah, the last line is the thing I am looking for. Thanks for your help. 
I am really appreciate it. 
Will update asap

Comment: Yes, after delete the typo syntax than the code work 
Thanks a lot, i stuck with it 2 days and you help me a lot :D 
Thanks a gain